# How to handle React requests that don't match "basename"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can I add some sort of Handler to my React Router to forward or redirect a URL like https://example.com/a/b;planId=TPM-123 to https://example.com/a/b/instance/TPM-123.

Today, when react runs localhost, the Chrome Console records these URLs as failures like...

```
<Router basename="/a/b"> is not able to match the URL "/a/b;planId=TPM-123" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything.
```

Can I put some handling on the Router to catch these and redirect? I really can't change basename...

```
...
export const AppRoutes: React.FunctionComponent = () => (
  <Routes>
    ...
    <Route
      path="/instance/:planId"
      element={<TpmPlanInstance />}
    />
    ...
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={
        <BackwardsCompSemiColonParams defaultRedirectPath="/search" />
      }
    />
  </Routes>
);
...
  return (
    <Router basename="/a/b">
      <MatomoRouterTracker />
      <GlobalErrors />
      <AppRoutes />
      # is there something I can add here to rewrite the URL and redirct onto basename?
    </Router>
  );
```

Because these strange "semi-colon delimited parameters" exist on the basename, they can't be handled by the Routes themselves. They never make it to the `Route.path="*"` we already have.

Alternatively...is there a way to "express" multiple Routers? Like one `Router basename="/a/b"` and one `Router basename="/a/b;planId="`?

How do I get the bizarre semi-colon delimited URL into my Routes on a React App?

Comment: Is your app actually being served from a `"/a/b"` subdirectory on the server? The `basename` prop should match where the app is served from. Is there a reason *why* the URL isn't using a queryString? It is bizarre. You may need to handle this server-side and convert `"/a/b;planId=TPM-123"` to `"/a/b?planId=TPM-123"` or similar.

Comment: Maybe, yes, @DrewReese. The k8s istio match is regex: /a/b.* . It is sadly funny, no one in the current org knows _why_ that obscure semi-colon delimited parameter convention was adopted. We are trying to keep these "legacy" links working, and with React here, it seems to be impossible. I can't find a way to describe basename as an expression or something. This may very well be "you can't do it at all...ever...and its dumb even asking".

Comment: I mean, yeah... the URL path is literally `"/a/b;planId=TPM-123"` and since the last path segment `"b;planId=TPM-123"` doesn't match `"b"` the router is expecting there's not much it can do about that. Like I said, I think you might need to configure the server hosting the app to return a redirect for the "weird" URL for the RRD/React-friendly version with queryString, and *still* serve up the root index.html file.

Comment: @DrewReese a solution that came in that works is to "detect" these before they get to Routes...and "rewrite" them there. Today we are doing this with a function that is triggering off `window.location.pathname.includes(';planId=')`. It works.

Comment: Ah yeah, that looks like it'd do the trick. Might be worth writing it up as an answer.